# Conculta con ajax y php

Tags: php, ajax, json

estoy tratando de hacer una app en cual me traiga los datos los clientes. La app esta hecha en html, phonegap, y quiero tratar de enteder un poco ajax para poder, atraves de él, traer los datos de mi php.

```
<?php
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=prueba", "root", "");
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM clientes');
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo "Clientes: ".$row['nombre'];
}
?>
```

Este php esta alojado en un domino y queria traer esos datos desde ahi. Tambien lei de usar JSON, pero me gustaria que me orienten un poco y aprender otro poco... gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejare un sencillo ejemplo:
html:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Ejemplo sencillo de AJAX</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
function realizaProceso(valorCaja1, valorCaja2){
        var parametros = {
                "valorCaja1" : valorCaja1,
                "valorCaja2" : valorCaja2
        };
        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros,
                url:   'ejemplo_ajax_proceso.php',
                type:  'post',
                beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                success:  function (response) {
                        $("#resultado").html(response);
                }
        });
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

Introduce valor 1

<input type="text" name="caja_texto" id="valor1" value="0"/> 


Introduce valor 2

<input type="text" name="caja_texto" id="valor2" value="0"/>

Realiza suma

<input type="button" href="javascript:;" onclick="realizaProceso($('#valor1').val(), $('#valor2').val());return false;" value="Calcula"/>

<br/>

Resultado: <span id="resultado">0</span>

</body>

</html>
```

archivo php(ejemplo_ajax_proceso.php):

```
<?php 
$resultado = $_POST['valorCaja1'] + $_POST['valorCaja2']; 
echo $resultado;
?>
```

en este sencillo ejemplo ves como desde el html envio a travez de ajax en una funcion llamanda (realizaProceso) dos parametros(valorCaja1, valorCaja2) estos recibe nuestro archivo php(ejemplo_ajax_proceso.php)
este php recibe mediante el metodo post hago una simple suma de estos dos valores y lsto retorno el resultado, puedes adaptar a tus necesidades es decir retornar consultas a la base de datos entre otros...
suerte !!
[EJEMPLO PASO A PASO](https://cybmeta.com/ajax-con-json-y-php-ejemplo-paso-a-paso)

Comment: Gracias @diego-avila, voy a leer lo que me enviaste asi le tomo el ritmo a eso... je...

Answer (score 0):

Para responder con un json a partir de los datos de tu base de datos,puedes utilizar:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM clientes');
$stmt->execute();
$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Con esto obtienes un json formado de la siguiente forma:

```
    {'atributo1TablaClientes':'valorAtributo',
     'atributo2TablaClientes':'valorAtributo',...}
```

en tu caso: {'nombre':'José',...}.

Eso por el lado del servidor. Ahora, para realizar una llamada con ajax para solicitar ese json resultado, podes usar [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Por ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    async:false
    type: "GET",
    // Formato de datos que se espera en la respuesta
    dataType: "json",
    // URL a la que se enviará la solicitud Ajax
    url: "script.php",
})
 .done(function( response ) {

         console.log( "JSON recibido: " + response );

 })
 .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
     if ( console && console.log ) {
         console.log( "Error: " +  textStatus);
     }
});
```

De esta forma estas realizando una llamada de manera asíncrona al servidor solicitando el archivo 'script.php' (tu archivo php). El procesamiento de la llamada por parte el servidor consiste en consultar a la base de datos, obtener el resultado, darle un formato json y por último retornar ese json. Luego lo recibís en el cliente (**reponse** de la función en **.done**) y lo mostrás por consola o haces un procesos de esos datos.

Comment: Gracias tambien @mlstud... trataba de hacer algo como lo que me pasaste de lo cual voy a leer mas y como dije anteriormente, ponerme a ritmo...