# Error al generar campo para JSON desde PHP

Tags: php, json

Estoy tratando de pasar un lista de noticias por JSON desde PHP

```
<?php
...
$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM noticias');
$sql->execute();

while($row = $sql->fetch()) {
  $data['titulo'] .= " ".$row->titulo." ";    
}

echo json_encode($data);   
exit();
?>
```

El problema es que como resultado me trae esto: `{"titulo":"  "}` y no la lista de los títulos de las noticias. No sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Tenés valores en la columna `titulo` de la tabla `noticias`?

Comment: @Sebastian prueba poner antes del `exit();`  `echo json_last_error();` para ver que error te arroja.

Comment: Para poder responder a la pregunta hacen falta algo más de información: ¿cuál es la estructura de la tabla noticias? ¿es la misma que el del JSON? ¿qué es `$data` y qué valor tiene `$data['titulo']` cuando se asigna? ¿Recibes algún error o warning cuando ejecutas el código?

Comment: Bueno, deberías hacer algo muy lógico que se hace, y es poner puntos de interrupción a todo el proceso, así sabrías, en que momento exacto la información no esta haciendo lo que quieres, o simplemente, la ocnsulta no se esta ejecutando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fijate si esto te resulta útil:

```
$dataTitulos = array();
while($row = $sql->fetch())
{
    array_push($dataTitulos, $row->titulo);
}
$data['titulo'] = $dataTitulos;

echo json_encode($data);
exit();
```

Comment: gracias, probe ambos y como resultado me esto: **{"titulos:":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]}**

Comment: ¿Tienes datos en las tablas?

Comment: si claro... hay una lista de 16 titulos de noticias

Comment: y tampoco tengo problemas con la coneccion

Comment: ¿los nombres de los campos de las tablas estan en minisculas o mayusculas?

Comment: Haber intenta con usar la function fetch_array()

Comment: Los campos estan bien e hice la prueba con fetch_array() y no funciono

Comment: Deberías añadir una pequeña descripción de cómo funciona esta solución y por qué solucionaría el problema expuesto en la pregunta. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad. Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones.

Answer (score 1):

prueba especificando el tipo de fetch

```
 $connSTR = "mysql:host=".$db['hostname'].";dbname=".$db['database'].";charset=utf8mb4";
 $conn = null;
 try {
     $conn = new PDO($connSTR, $db['username'], $db['password']);
     // set the PDO error mode to exception
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     // echo ("Connected successfully ".PHP_EOL);
 }
 catch(PDOException $e)
     {
     // echo ("Connection failed: ". $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL);
      }
 $result = "";
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE 1";
 $sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $sth->execute() or die($sth->errorInfo());
 while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
      $result .= $row['titulo']." ";
 endwhile;

 $data = array("titulo"=>$result);
 echo json_encode($data);
 exit();
```

yo uso `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` por costumbre (y accedo por `$row['columna'];`) en tu caso sería `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` para acceder por `$row->columna`

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes que el usuario usa PDO? ¿O que el usuario está inicializando `$data` correctamente?

Comment: no lo sé, por eso dice "Prueba ...". Siendo que OP ya ha preguntado usando PDO es mas probable que haya mezclado la sintaxis objeto/array a que se le hayan escapado un store_result, bind_result, etc... para usar `->fetch()` con msqli, fijate https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/154363/81450 y como mezclar las respuestas dadas allí llevaría a algo parecido a lo que vemos en esta pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Por la sintaxis parece que estás usando `PDO`. Parece ser que el no se está llenando el `array`con los `id` de los títulos sin embargo sí se están consultando correctamente con lo que es posible que el error esté en el tipo de `fetch`.

Una posible solución podría ser especificarlo directamente como parámetro de la función `fetch()` quedando de este modo:

```
$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
```

El código completo quedaría así:

```
<?php
...
$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT titulo FROM noticias');
$sql->execute();

while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
 $data['titulo'] .= " ".$row->titulo." ";    
}

echo json_encode($data);   
exit();
?>
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que el usuario está usando PDO? ¿Por qué pones `$data['titulo'][]` en lugar de `$data['titulo']` como en la pregunta? (además de cambiar `$row->titulo` por `$row['titulo']`)

Comment: Juraría que lo vi en la pregunta pero parece que no... mañana arreglamos este desaguisado.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php
...
$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM noticias');
$sql->execute();
$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Si hay registros nuestra variable $results seria igual a lo que obtengamos del query, si no contendrá un warning de que no hay registros obtenidos por la consulta.

$results = (count($sql) > 0) ? $sql : array("error"=>"No hay opciones en la BD");

//Lo convertimos a json

$arrayJson = json_encode($results);

//Verificamos el contenido de nuestro json_encode
print_r($arrayJson);

exit();
?>
```

Comment: Este código asume que la estructura del JSON va a ser la misma que la del registro de la base de datos, lo cual no parece por lo que está puesto en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Puede que estas recuperando datos en una codificación que no es utf8, intenta poner:

Si estas utilizando **mysql**

`mysql_query ('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')` antes de su consulta `SELECT`

Si estas utilizando **PDO**

```
$sql->exec("set names utf8");
```

O si utilizas **mysqli**

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

> También lo puedes poner después de tu conexión a la BD

Comment: ¿Por qué tener una codificación diferente de utf8 sería un problema en este caso? Tal y como está escrito, casi parece más un comentario que una respuesta.

Comment: 1.- Porque el compañero no le marca ningún error en la consulta, pero al parecer si esta retornando valores...
2.- Se devuelve NULL si el json no se puede decodificar o si los datos codificados son más profundos que el límite de recursión. 
@AlvaroMontoro

Comment: Creo que no me expliqué bien: ¿por qué poner un charset utf8 resolvería el problema? ¿cuál es el problema y cómo lo resolvería esto?

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes crear ordenadamente el `Array` y luego lo pasas a **JSON**, el problema es que no estas guardando bien los títulos en un `Aarray` para luego convertirlo:

```
    $array = array();
    $datos["Libros"] = array();

    while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $tmp = array();//Array que almacena los datos de la consulta
    $tmp["titulo"] = $row["titulo"];//Guarda los datos en el objecto "titulo"
    array_push($array,$tmp);//Crea el array con los datos del array "$tmp"

    }

    $datos["Libros"] = $array;
    echo json_encode($datos);
```

Comment: ¿Podrías aplicar lo que sugieres al código de la pregunta? Además, parece que estás usando MySQLi (por el `fetch_assoc`), ¿seguro que es lo que está usando el usuario?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que JSON espera un `array` y le remites una cadena, prueba en tu bucle que sea un `array` en lugar de una cadena y de esa forma va a ser posible convertirlo a un formato JSON.

```
<?php
...
$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT titulo FROM noticias');
$sql->execute();

while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
$data['titulo'][] = $row->titulo;    
}

echo json_encode($data);   
exit();
?>
```

Para brindar un mejor contexto relacionado al uso de arreglos indexados u objetos anónimos a continuación un ejemplo relacionado:

```
// FETCH_ASSOC -- Arreglo indexado ver ref. bibliografica
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT titulo FROM noticias");
// Especificamos el fetch mode antes de llamar a fetch()
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Ejecutamos
$stmt->execute();
// Mostramos los resultados
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo "Nombre: {$row["titulo"]} <br>";
}
// FETCH_OBJ -- Objeto anónimo ver Ref. bibliografica
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT titulo FROM noticias");
// Ejecutamos
$stmt->execute();
// Ahora vamos a indicar el fetch mode cuando llamamos a fetch:
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo "Nombre: " . $row->titulo . "<br>";
}
```

Bibliografía: https://diego.com.es/tutorial-de-pdo

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: gracias, pero como dije anteriormente, me da como resultado: **{"titulos:":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]}**

Comment: cambia el "*" por los campos específicos que requieres de la siguiente manera: SELECT titulo FROM noticias, para que te permita ver el valué de ese ítem y confirma que esta apuntando al esquema correcto y que tu tabla en ese esquema tiene datos. Saludos.

Comment: claro, es que hago la misma consulta con un simple while y me trae los datos, el problema es cuando agrego json

Comment: mira si con |||| echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>"; ||| si te genera nulos también, si es así es algo relacionado a la consulta y no al formato Json. Saludos.

Comment: `json_encode` admite cualquier tipo de dato menos resource, por lo que   una cadena (`$data['titulo']`) podría ser una entrada válida con una salida válida. Además, el `json_encode` se está haciendo de `$data` que sí parece un array asociativo (aunque la definición no se ve en el código compartido).

Comment: Buenas tardes Alvaro si efectivamente no es un array asociativo, en realidad los ejemplos que enuncio son de objetos anónimos y arreglos indexados, por tanto acabo de actualizar mi respuesta segun lo que me informas de la misma, en la bibliografía que comparto se puede ver la parte conceptual de los ítems relacionados. Saludos y muchas gracias por tu apreciación.